# How to sort huge dataset with Spark Sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a partitioned table with about 2 billion rows in hive like:

```
id, num, num_partition
1, 1253742321.53124121, 12
4, 1253742323.53124121, 12
2, 1353742324.53124121, 13
3, 1253742325.53124121, 12
```

And I want to have a table like:

```
id, rank,rank_partition
89,         1, 0
...
1, 1253742321,12
7, 1253742322,12
4, 1253742323,12
8, 1253742324,12
3, 1253742325,12
...
2, 1353742324,13
...
```

I have tried to do this:

```
df = spark.sql("select *, rank/10000000 from (select id,row_number() over(order by num asc) rank from table)t1")
```

It was very slow, since order by will use only 1 reducer

and I've tried to do this:

```
df = spark.sql("select *, rank/10000000 from (select id,row_number() over(distribute by num_partition order by num_partition asc,num asc) rank from table)t1")
```

But in the result the num_partition hasn't been sorted